# Displaying NY state with counties map via .shp and TopoJSON

Tags: javascript, d3.js, shapefile, topojson

The end goal is to display a map of New York state with county boundaries, and then map lat,lon points onto it.

**This has led to two main questions:**

1. Generally, what is the `object` argument mentioned in the [topojson client API reference](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/API-Reference) supposed to be? e.g. `topojson.mesh(topology, object, [filter])`
2. What `object` and `[filter]` arguments can I provide (or what other methods can I use) to get NY state county boundaries to show up correctly?

**Acquiring the .shp file:**

- I got the shape file of NY state and its counties from this CIGUR download:
  http://cugir.mannlib.cornell.edu/bucketinfo.jsp?id=7865
- Specifically, I used the `cty036.shp` file within the download, you can download just this specific file [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45679066/cty036.shp)

**Viewing the .shp file:**

- The `cty036.shp` looks good when being displayed using http://www.mapshaper.org

[image: .shp file displayed using mapshaper.org]
**Converting the .shp file to TopoJSON**:

- The TopoJSON version of this .shp file was created by using the TopoJSON export feature of mapshaper.org
- I named this file `cty036Topo.json`, you can download the file I'm using [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45679066/cty036Topo.json)

**Displaying the TopoJSON file using D3**:

- The code I'm using...

  ```
  var width = 960,
  height = 500;

  var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
      .center([-74.875366, 42.88])
      .scale(4500)
      .translate([width / 2, height / 2])

  var path = d3.geo.path()
      .projection(projection)

  var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .style("border", "1px solid black");

  d3.json("data/cty036Topo.json", function(error, ny) {
      if (error) return console.error(error);
      console.log(ny)
      svg.append("path")
         .datum(topojson.feature(ny, ny.objects.cty036))
         .datum(topojson.mesh(ny, ny.arcs, ))
         .attr("d", path);
  });
  ```
- The above javascript produces the following NY map in the browser:

[image: NY state using D3]
**Attempting to display county boundaries:**

- Now, attempting to use topojson.mesh in the callback to display county boundaries

  ```
  d3.json("data/cty036Topo.json", function(error, ny) {
      if (error) return console.error(error);
      console.log(ny)
      svg.append("path")
         .datum(topojson.mesh(ny))
         .attr("d", path);
  });
  ```

[image: NY state map with messed up county boundaries]

You can see this resembles NY state's counties but is not right. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Set `path { fill: none; stroke: black; }` in your CSS.